# How to make the dropdown not to include a heading if it already exists

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like someone to help me in the code provided here. It simply has to check if all the elements within the single quote of the if statement (block) match it's corresponding m.Menu_Item_Name in the database. This is simply a dropdown on my aspx page together with jQuery.

If the elements within the if and the rest of if-else statements match m.Menu_Item_Name, then show the particular heading "Accountants", "Reports" and "Other" respectively. Now the problem is that every element comes under its particular heading, however, they are repeating. Means that every heading appear more than one time and show just a single element every time. I just want to group them such that they appear once yet show all the elements which belong to that heading.

Any help will highly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 if (m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Financial Statements' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Cover Sheet' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Letters' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Invites')
    {
        lielm += '<li><strong>Accountants</strong></li>';
        lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
    }
 else if (m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Income Statement' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Balance Sheet' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Income Details' || m.Menu_Item_Name =='Ledger')
    {
        lielm += '<li><strong>Reports</strong></li>';
        lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
    } 
 else
    {
        lielm += '<li><strong>Other</strong></li>';
        lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
    }
```

Comment: I can share more details as well, if needed. The code I have provided is just the area where the logic need to be implemented.

Comment: This code in the loop, right? Show the code with the loop

Comment: There is nothing special in it. It is just for each loop. Here it is $.each(obj.data, function (i, m) { the code goes here });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add the headers in an every iteration. You should do it only once.
Place this somewhere before the loop:

```
var accountantsItems = [];
var reportsItems = [];
var otherItems = [];
```

then change your loop body to create a separate arrays:

```
if (m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Financial Statements' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Cover Sheet' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Letters' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Invites')
{
    accountantsItems.push(m);
}
if (m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Income Statement' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Balance Sheet' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Income Details' || m.Menu_Item_Name =='Ledger')
{
    reportsItems.push(m);
} 
else 
{
    otherItems.push(m);
}
```

then, after the loop run another three loops for three arrays:

```
var isAccountantsHeaderAdded = false;
var isReportsHeaderAdded = false;
var isOtherHeaderAdded = false;

$.each(accountantsItems, function( index, m ) {
    if (!isAccountantsHeaderAdded){
        lielm += '<li><strong>Accountants</strong></li>';
        isAccountantsHeaderAdded = true;
    }
    lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
});

$.each(reportsItems, function( index, m ) {
    if (!isReportsHeaderAdded){
        lielm += '<li><strong>Reports</strong></li>';
        isReportsHeaderAdded = true;
    }
    lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
}


$.each(otherItems, function( index, m ) {
    if (!isOtherHeaderAdded){
        lielm += '<li><strong>Other</strong></li>';
        isOtherHeaderAdded= true;
    }
    lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Hi @Albert. What if the code act in a crazy way? Only the first item in Accounting heading is showing while the rest of three from the same heading are showing under Other heading. What might be wrong with it?

Comment: Once again thank you @Albert for the support you've provided. It's working fine.